# Windows "File open" dialog can't see new folders in My Documents?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

This is something which has irritated me for a while:

I have a windows machine which has some custom folders in 'My Documents' for various types of files. These show up fine in Explorer, but don't seem to be visible to any of the "File Browse" type dialogs (eg File>Open in any of the Office applications, Add/Remove Programs, etc).

Is there a way to force these dialogs to show *all* folders in the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those folders are [virtual ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_folder) (or maybe [special folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder)). Which means that they are not really folders, and cannot appear in application dialogs that don't know how to handle them.

Comment: Hm, ok - so would any folder I created in that location be created as a virtual folder? Or is there a way to create a 'real' folder?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to locate the folder(s) by going through:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Your User Name\My Documents

instead of clicking the My Documents folder directly.

Comment: They also do not show up when clicking directly to this location in the dialog, so I suspect the above comment about them being 'virtual' is probably on the right track. thanks though!